# standard notation behind the QT reference documentation

Tags: qt, notation

I've searched extensively for an answer but to no avail. I am progressing well with self-tutoring of the basics of PyQT5. I am using  http://pyqt.sourceforge.net to gain insight into how classes and functions link together but I am finding the QT reference documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ a useful means of gaining further insight. 
I can pick up on the fact that there is a standard notation running through the documentation but I cannot follow what various symbols and reoccurring text refers to. There also appear to be many parameters and nested parameters applied. I paste a few samples below:

```
void    setFocus(Qt::FocusReason reason)

render(QPainter *painter, const QPoint &targetOffset = QPoint(), const QRegion &sourceRegion = QRegion(), RenderFlags renderFlags = RenderFlags( DrawWindowBackground | DrawChildren ))

qmake:  QT += widgets

enum    RenderFlag { DrawWindowBackground, DrawChildren, IgnoreMask }
```

My question: is the documentation following an industry standard notation when it uses symbols such as "|" ? If so, is there a reference I can refer to to interpret the notation? I've combed through the QT website but can find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is a C++ library and the snippets you are showing are excerpts from C++ code. 
except for the qmake line which is qmake code.

`|` is the [bitwise OR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) operator. The `enum` `RenderFlag` consists of flags (where usually one unique bit is set) which can be combined via this operator.

Comment: Thanks, so to understand the Qt online documentation effectively, I need a grounding in C++. Perhaps I have to restrict myself to the pyqt.sourceforge.net as a reference in the short term.

Comment: @Gary I think the Qt documentation is still a valuable resource and I don’t think it’s necessary to understand the C++ details to understand how the classes are meant to be used. I also think you will even start to understand the details with time.

Comment: Hello Darklighter - you're right. 2 days after being aware that it is C++ notation and it is beginning to make more sense. Now it's only a case of putting the time in to learn. thanks again.